# npm module stream not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Since yesterday our tests don't not run anymore.

Error: `module stream not found`

After research we found that stream is available as core node module:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#apicontent

And also available from npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream

After `npm install` our package-lock.json contains of the npm package 'stream' and this is probably the problem.

Is it possible to create npm packages with the name of a core module?

We didn't solve the failure yet, but maybe it comes from name collision of `stream`.

Any experience with this?

EDIT:

`npm list` shows that no npm package has `stream` as dependencie

```
├─┬ stream@0.0.2
│ └── emitter-component@1.1.1
```

Comment: We do not have `stream` in our package.json. And after research all other node_modules neither

Answer (score 1):

removing `package-lock.json` and install packages via 
`yarn` solves the problem.

We still have to investigate this problem. Because our CI use npm.

Answer (score 0):

NPM is a package manager. Some modules names are reserved, like the [`fs` module](http://npmjs.com/package/fs)
, but since Node API evolves and introduces new native modules every now and then, there will always be community-made modules that already exists with those names.

However, according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/562) :

> built-in modules always take precedence [over npm modules]

You can try to remove the npm module, but maybe you should check your Node version.

By the way you don't need to add Node's core modules in your package.json file.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer.
Removing node_modules and a fresh `npm install` does not solve the problem.

Comment: If you do `npm install` but you still have the `stream` module in your package.json file, it will keep installing it. Try `npm remove stream` (add the `-S` flag to remove it from the package.json)

Comment: we have `stream` only in `package-lock.json`(automaticaly after `npm install`) ... not in `package.json`